# The works of González-Acuña and Duchon from 70s and 80s

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds

I would like to access the following two works of González-Acuña from 1970:

> González-Acuña, F. Dehn’s construction on knots. Bol. Soc. Mat. Mexicana (2) 15 (1970), 58–79.

and

> González-Acuña, F. On homology spheres. Thesis (Ph.D.)–Princeton University. 1970. 127 pp. ProQuest LLC.

plus the Ph.D. thesis of Duchon:

> Duchon, Nicholas. Involutions of plumbed manifolds. Thesis (Ph.D.)–University of Maryland, College Park. 1982. 102 pp. ProQuest LLC.

I would be very happy if someone shares copies of these papers or provides links to them.

**Note:** Besides not finding them online, I was not able to reach González-Acuña by e-mail (indicated in his last article) and one of my e-mails got an alert like "Undelivered Mail Report".

**Note 2:** Direct access to González-Acuña's thesis is possible, see comments.

Comment: The thesis is on [ProQuest](https://www.proquest.com/docview/302426826), as your citation indicates.

Comment: I am also very interested in obtaining a copy of the first paper.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks! Does it require an institutional login? Because I cannot access it now.

Comment: You can get the first 30 pages as a preview.  I managed to get the entire thesis via my institution.

Comment: Have you tried asking at your institution's library for the article in Bol Mat. Soc. Mex? A library can often obtain scanned copies of articles via interlibrary loan. It's usually under a day.

Comment: I have a print copy of Fico's article, but I will be back to my office until mid-July; if by that time you have not obtained a copy of the article, please let me know and I can scan it and e-mail it to you. On the other hand, the UNAM Math Institute library has an email address at the bottom of the first page in (just before the list of new books): http://biblioteca.matem.unam.mx/ Perhaps they can get you a scan copy of the paper.

Comment: Both MPIM and González-Acuña provided a copy of the article. Unfortunately, I have no right to share it!

Answer (score 2):

All of these papers are currently available online.

[González-Acuña, F. Dehn’s construction on knots. Bol. Soc. Mat. Mexicana (2) 15 (1970), 58–79.](https://www.boletin.math.org.mx/pdf/2/15/BSMM(2).15.58-79.pdf)

[González-Acuña, F. On homology spheres. Thesis (Ph.D.)–Princeton University. 1970. 127 pp. ProQuest LLC](https://www.proquest.com/docview/302426826?sourcetype=Dissertations%20&%20Theses)

[Duchon, Nicholas. Involutions of plumbed manifolds. Thesis (Ph.D.)–University of Maryland, College Park. 1982. 102 pp. ProQuest LLC](https://www.proquest.com/docview/303246251/85C4C6C75A2F4DEEPQ/1?accountid=10474&sourcetype=Dissertations%20&%20Theses)

The middle link [was provided in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424375/the-works-of-gonz%C3%A1lez-acu%C3%B1a-and-duchon-from-70s-and-80s#comment1090833_424375) by LSpice. For both the second and third link, I had to log in to proquest via my institution but didn't need to be on campus.